# Keep tracking faces by using the front camera

Tags: android, callback, android-camera, preview, face-detection

I try to make an apps to keep tracking the number of faces detected by the camera, however, through the logcat, I found that the program never invoke the onPreviewFrame method and I dont know the reason.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Context context = null;
BackGround bg=new BackGround();
FDR fdr = new FDR();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this.getApplicationContext();
    bg.execute();

}

private class BackGround extends  AsyncTask <Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params) {  
        while(!isCancelled()){  
            fdr.startFaceDetection(context);
            Log.d("result", String.valueOf(fdr.getnumberOfFaceDetected()));
             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        fdr.FreeCamera();
        return null;
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate( Integer ...progress ){        
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    bg.cancel(true);
    fdr.FreeCamera();
}   
}
```

The code of the below class is basically a sample code from another website.

```
public class FDR {      
protected Camera mCameraDevice = null;
private long mScanBeginTime = 0;   
private long mScanEndTime = 0;   
private long mSpecPreviewTime = 0;  
private long mSpecStopTime = 0;
private long mSpecCameraTime = 0;
private static final String TAG = null;
private int orientionOfCamera ;   
private Context con=null;
private int numberOfFaceDetected;    

public void startFaceDetection(Context cont) {  
    con=cont;
    try {  
            FreeCamera();           
           mCameraDevice = Camera.open(1); 
            if (mCameraDevice != null)  
                Log.i(TAG, "open cameradevice success! ");  
        } catch (Exception e) {           
            mCameraDevice = null;  
            Log.w(TAG, "open cameraFail");  

            return;  
    }   

    Log.i(TAG, "startFaceDetection");  
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCameraDevice.getParameters();  
    setCameraDisplayOrientation(1,mCameraDevice);              

    mCameraDevice.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback(){  
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){  
            mScanEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();   
            mSpecPreviewTime = mScanEndTime - mScanBeginTime;    
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreviewFrame and mSpecPreviewTime = " + String.valueOf(mSpecPreviewTime));  
            Camera.Size localSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize(); 
            YuvImage localYuvImage = new YuvImage(data, 17, localSize.width, localSize.height, null);  
            ByteArrayOutputStream localByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            localYuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, localSize.width, localSize.height), 80, localByteArrayOutputStream);   
            byte[] arrayOfByte = localByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();  
            FreeCamera();   
            StoreByteImage(arrayOfByte);  
        }  
    });  

    mCameraDevice.startPreview();   
    Log.i(TAG,"StartPreviewed");  
    mScanBeginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}  


public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int paramInt, Camera paramCamera){  
    CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();  
    Camera.getCameraInfo(paramInt, info);  
    int rotation = ((WindowManager)con.getSystemService("window")).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();  
    int degrees = 0;  
    Log.i(TAG,"getRotation's rotation is " + String.valueOf(rotation));  
    switch (rotation) {  
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;  
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;  
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;  
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;  
    }  

    orientionOfCamera = info.orientation;    
    int result;  
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {  
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;  
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror  
    } else {  // back-facing  
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;  
    }  
    paramCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);    
}  
public void StoreByteImage(byte[] paramArrayOfByte){  
    mSpecStopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    mSpecCameraTime = mSpecStopTime - mScanBeginTime;  

    Log.i(TAG, "StoreByteImage and mSpecCameraTime is " + String.valueOf(mSpecCameraTime));  

    BitmapFactory.Options localOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();  
        Bitmap localBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramArrayOfByte.length, localOptions);  
        int i = localBitmap1.getWidth();  
        int j = localBitmap1.getHeight(); 
        Matrix localMatrix = new Matrix();  
        //int k = cameraResOr;  
        Bitmap localBitmap2 = null;  
        FaceDetector localFaceDetector = null;  

    switch(orientionOfCamera){  
        case 0:  
            localFaceDetector = new FaceDetector(i, j, 1);  
                    localMatrix.postRotate(0.0F, i / 2, j / 2);  
                    localBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(i, j, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  
            break;  
        case 90:  
            localFaceDetector = new FaceDetector(j, i, 1);   
                    localMatrix.postRotate(-270.0F, j / 2, i / 2);  
                    localBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(i, j, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  
            break;                        
        case 180:  
            localFaceDetector = new FaceDetector(i, j, 1);  
                    localMatrix.postRotate(-180.0F, i / 2, j / 2);  
                    localBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(i, j, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);  
            break;  
        case 270:  
            localFaceDetector = new FaceDetector(j, i, 1);  
                    localMatrix.postRotate(-90.0F, j / 2, i / 2);  
                    localBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(j, i, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); 
            break;  
    }  

    FaceDetector.Face[] arrayOfFace = new FaceDetector.Face[1];  
        Paint localPaint1 = new Paint();  
        Paint localPaint2 = new Paint();  
    localPaint1.setDither(true);  
        localPaint2.setColor(-65536);  
        localPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
        localPaint2.setStrokeWidth(2.0F);  
        Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas();  
        localCanvas.setBitmap(localBitmap2);  
        localCanvas.setMatrix(localMatrix);  
        localCanvas.drawBitmap(localBitmap1, 0.0F, 0.0F, localPaint1); 

    numberOfFaceDetected = localFaceDetector.findFaces(localBitmap2, arrayOfFace); 
        localBitmap2.recycle();  
        localBitmap1.recycle();   
}  

public int getnumberOfFaceDetected(){
    return numberOfFaceDetected;
}
public void FreeCamera() {
    if (mCameraDevice != null) {
        // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
        // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
        // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
        // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
        mCameraDevice.stopPreview();
        mCameraDevice.release();    
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. To receive callbacks, you must first [`setPreviewDisplay()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewDisplay(android.view.SurfaceHolder)).
2. Consider opening Camera once, before the loop, and running face detection with setOneShotPreviewCallback()
3. There are much more efficient methods to convert the YUV preview frame to RGB bitmap than using JPEG intermediate.
4. Android Camera has a fairly fast and robust built-in face detector, you start it by calling `startFaceDetection()`, and then you will be receiving the results as callback.